# How do I generate totally a random number at a time?

Tags: c++

I want to create 3 random number at a time (simultaneously). However, they returned me the same numbers at a time even though they are actually random. Example:

```
------------------------
Variable:   A   B   C
------------------------
Time 1  :   5   5   5
Time 2  :   3   3   3
Time 3  :   9   9   9
------------------------
```

They suppose to be different numbers at all. From the observation, I can see that my code can only pick a random number at a time (interval 1 second). Here is my generator code that I'm using:

```
unsigned int CMain::GenerateRandom(int min, int max)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
    unsigned int random_integer; 
    int lowest = min, highest = max; 
    int range = (highest - lowest) + 1;

    random_integer = lowest + int(range * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));

    return random_integer;
}
```

How could I generate a totally random numbers at a time? Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your issue here is you're resetting the random seed every call using the current time which you shouldn't do.

Call `srand()` once before querying any random numbers - that's all and more than enough.

Right now you always reset your random seed to the exact same value (as you use current time). Random numbers in PCs aren't really random at all. The same seed will always result in the same set of random numbers generated later on. This is intentional and used in e.g. savegames for games to always have the same things happen without having to save every random number generated, etc.

Comment: So how do I fix this? I'm not so familiar with generating random numbers.

Comment: Just move your call to `srand()` to the start of your program - don't do it in that function and you're fine.

Comment: `Random numbers in PCs aren't really random at all.` That's not exactly true. Specifically, it's a Microsoft problem. Linux has `/dev/random` which uses hardware sources. But for simple (non-crypto) purposes, even Windows has a decent algorithm (`rand_s()`).

Comment: @MSalters: It's true for `rand()`, which is defined to return a pseudo-random number. http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand I don't see what `/dev/random` or Microsoft has to do with this issue.

Comment: Well, that's kind of obvious: a PRNG is pretty much defined by _not_ being random. But this answer basically said that _all_ RNG's  in PC's are PRNG: "will **always** result in the same set of random numbers". That's just not right. Second counterexample: VIA CPU's have hardware RNGs.

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `srand()` each time you generate a new random number. Call it once at the start of your program and then just call `rand()` each time you need a new random number.

FYI: Values returned from `rand()` are not "totally random". They are pseudo-random numbers generated by an algorithm. (This is not related to your question though.)

Comment: Well, your additional information actually IS related in my opinion. Cause the predictability (it being pseudo-random) IS the issue here.

Comment: So I just need to change from `srand()` to `rand()`?

Comment: No, you still need `srand()` at the start of your program. And you still need to call `rand()` when you need a new random number. The code you posted calls both functions each time you need a random number.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling srand() for every iteration. Srand() is setting a seed based on the current timestamp. Therefore you only need to call srand() once, and just call rand() to generate a new pseudo-random number. I say pseudo-random because computers cannot generate truly random numbers.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
int i, r;

srand(time(0));

for(i = 0; r <= 20000; i++) 
r = rand();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a complete rand() usage?

Comment: But I can't see the code. Do you paste in an URL? Perhaps, you forgot to link your text.

Answer (score 2):

**time(0)** changes slowly. If you query **GenerateRandom** quickly you can get the same number multiple times.

But in general, that isn't a right way to generate random numbers. You want to seed the random number generator only once, before any other function uses it. Treat **rand** as a global singleton object. If any of your functions modifies its seed by calling **srand**, then the change will affect all other calls to **rand**.